# Pausing a Swing Thread untill a javafx dialog has closed

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, javafx

I have an action that is written in the event dispatch thread, this action calls a method createDialog() which goes away and creates a Swing Dialog and returns it, after this method call we check if the dialog has been canceled and then it returns the result of this. unfortunately my company want me to change this createDialog() method so that it returns a JavaFX dialog instead of a Swing Dialog.

My problem comes when we check if the dialog has been cancelled, because we are in the Event Dispatch Thread I then need to do the Platform.runLater to put myself into a FX thread but obviously because I have created a new thread the program will run on and not wait for the dialog to close. I have tried to pause the Event Dispatch thread until the Javafx thread has completed but pausing the Event Dispatch thread has resulted in the UI becoming unresponsive.

Is there a way to make the Event Dispatch thread wait for a javafx thread to complete? I am fine with using a jfxPanel but i still seem to have the same problem. I am sure I am doing something wrong and it is actually a simple thing to fix but some advice would be great. (I am not able to change the Action because of company guidelines).

Thanks in Advance.

as a small code example:

```
 //we are currently in the EDT (I can't control the start of this)

//creates the dialog i want this to create the FX Dialog
m_dialog = createDialog();

//because my dialog is in the FX Thread the EDT will hit this part of code before the dialog has been closed.
        if (m_dialog.isCancelled()) {
            return IActionEnum.eCanceled;
        }

    return IActionEnum.eCompleted;
```

Comment: Use the [Foxtrot](http://foxtrot.sourceforge.net/) lib. This lib allows to "stop" EDT without to loose the UI responsibility.

Comment: Is there any way to fix this problem without the use of a library, Generally my company doesn't like the use of them. this is definitely a possible solution though thanks.

Comment: It's a very small lib, so you can try to integrate the source code in your application.

Comment: I will have a look into doing this thanks for your help mate i would never have thought about a lib to fix this problem.

Comment: Even if you seem aware of EDT and JavaFX thread, I suggest you to read this [oracle's example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm) and also to post a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't want to make UI threads "wait" for something to happen, as this will make your UI unresponsive. I would try to refactor this as "when the dialog closes, execute XXX code". E.g. you could disable the entire Swing UI, show the dialog, and then when the dialog closes enable the Swing UI again. (Obviously you also have to manage the two UI threads here, but that should just be a matter of using the right combination of `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` and `Platform.runLater(...)`.)

Comment: @James_D this is the kind of thing i have attempted to do, The problem comes with the framework i am working with, the Swing Thread is started in an area of code i don't have access to so the methods i am working with are currently in the EDT and so i am struggling to find a way to "Disable the Swing UI" if there is a way to do this from the EDT itself or some magic i can do on the FX Thread that will stop the code running through that would be fantastic

Comment: UI threads are *always* started in code you don't have access to. "Stop the code running through" just doesn't make sense in this context. This is event-driven programming. What is actually going to run? The only things the EDT does (similarly for the JavaFX Application Thread) are render the UI and process user events. All you need to do is not actually have any code that is executed after you show the FX dialog. If you need to process the results of the dialog, do that in a listener that responds to the dialog closing.

Comment: The code snippet you posted is simply working from the wrong design: your method should not return a result. You should call another method when the dialog completes to process the result (have the method accept some kind of callback if needed).

Comment: I am working on one "Action" which is a part of an Action Framework there is an "onActon" method that is called which is where the dialog is created (the one i need to make FX), this onAction method needs to return "Completed" or "Canceled" depending on what has been pressed in the dialog. are you saying that i can put a listener after i make the dialog on the EDT that can see if the FX Dialog is closed.

Comment: sorry i didn't read that last comment before i my other one, the framework requires this to be returned, I can't change the framework only this action is there a way to do what i want to do but keep this method returning the result?